# Set a password at boot before recovery mode on Android Q Huawei P30 Pro

Tags: boot, security, password-protection

on my old cellphone, I could set a password that was asked at startup to protect it I did not find any similar setting in Android 10

I need help to properly secure my cell phone in case I lose it

Comment: your phone is very secure with android 10 standard file-based encryption and locked bootloader. recovery/fastboot mode is useless (huawei does not provide unlock codes anymore). your screenlock is part of the encryption key, a 6 digit pin is sufficient against bruteforcing. if you choose pattern, gatekeeper will wipe your device after 10 attempts https://source.android.com/security/features

Comment: https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2018/05/demystifying-android-physical-acquisition